# intellij shortcut - how to fold all javadocs + method implementations

Tags: java, intellij-idea, folding

I can't find some IntelliJ IDEA shortcuts.

When I go to a class, I want to be able to see only the method signature without additional details.

Here is what I mean. Before:

[image]

And after:

[image]

Is there a shortcut for this?

Comment: Don't provide information as image which can be text.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Code Folding of a whole file is](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/folding-and-expanding-code-blocks.html)

```
Ctrl+Shift+Minus and Ctrl+Shift+Numpad_Plus
```

or in the menu

> choose Code | Folding | Collapse All or Code | Folding | Expand All.

For more shortcuts for code folding:

[image: Code Folding Shortcuts in IntelliJ]

[Docs for Code Folding Shortcuts](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/code-folding-2.html)

Comment: In other words, Ctrl-Shift-+ or - either on the main keyboard or the numpad.

Answer (score 6):

Go to `File\Settings\Keymap\Main menu\Code\Folding` (or just search for "`Expand doc comments`" in Settings.

You can set a custom shortcut (i.e. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>-</kbd>) to expand or collapse all Javadocs in the file.